# Can we use sequences in oracle other than the first column?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sequence

When I tried executing the below statement error popped up showing

> "column not allowed here"

Here's my code

```sql
create table students(name varchar(10),id number);
create sequence seq
start with 1
increment by 100
nocycle ;
insert into students values('rishav',seq.next_val);
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can use sequence not only in the first column. 
But your code has a little mistake. If you want to get next value from sequence, you must use `nextval`.  So, just correct `seq.next_val` to `seq.nextval`